# Linux Kernel Module : Problem with kernel_write function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a problem using `kernel_write` function while I am developing LKM for Linux 4.14.73 version.

This is the part of my module where I am facing the issue :

```
void change_led_state(char *led_path, int led_value)
{


    printk("we are in change_led_state\n");
    size_t len = sizeof(led_value);
    char    lpath[64];
    ssize_t rk=0;

    strncpy(lpath, led_path, sizeof(lpath) - 1);
    lpath[sizeof(lpath) - 1] = '\0';
    f_led = filp_open(lpath, O_WRONLY , 0);

    if (f_led == NULL) {
        printk("Unable to access led\n");
        return;
    }


    rk = kernel_write(f_led, led_value, len, &f_led->f_pos);
    printk("rk = %d\n", rk);
    filp_close(f_led, NULL);
}
```

**rk** is usually getting a negative value. I think it must be positive. What's wrong with the function please ? How can I correct it ?

For more informations, I have the same code but in user-space program, and it's working fine, I just want to replace it to kernel space. This is the user space program :

```
void change_led_state(char *led_path, int led_value)
{
    char    lpath[64];
    FILE    *led_fd;

    strncpy(lpath, led_path, sizeof(lpath) - 1);
    lpath[sizeof(lpath) - 1] = '\0';

    led_fd = fopen(lpath, "w");

    if (led_fd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplekey: unable to access led\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(led_fd, "%d\n", led_value);

    fclose(led_fd);
}


void reset_leds(void)
{
    change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", 0);
}

void eval_keycode(int code)
{
    static int green_state = 0;

    switch (code) {
    case 260:
        printf("BTN pressed\n");

        // figure out red state
        green_state = green_state ? 0 : 1;

        change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", green_state);
        break;

    default :
        printf("Wrong Button was pressed\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

In the main fuction I just call eval_keycode function and it's working. What mistakes I have made ?

Comment: `rk is usually getting a negative value` which value/values exactly? `-14` looks like `EFAULT`, what is the `lpath` you are opening?

Comment: @KamilCuk rk = -14

Comment: The 2. argument to kernel_write is supposed to be a pointer, you are not passing in a pointer there.

Comment: @KamilCuk the path is defined as : #define LED_PATH "/sys/class/leds"

Comment: @nos that did not work

Comment: @gaston What did you do ? Maybe you did it wrong ? Are you also certain you should pass &f_led->f_pos as the last argument ?

Comment: There is no file at `/sys/class/leds`, it's a directory. Leds can be controlled with `/sys/class/leds/<device>/brightness`. Please show all the code that is needed to reproduce the problem. How do you call your function? What parameters you pass to the function? Why do you tap the `led_path` to 64 characters? Why do you pass integer value as the second parameter to `kernel_write`? How is `f_led` defined? Why do you pass `&f_led->f_pos` as the 4th parameter to `kernel_write`?  Ultimately, what do you want to do?

Comment: @KamilCuk Please Can you see the modifications I made to my question ? Thank you

Comment: what is `green`?

Comment: Why do you do `strncpy(lpath, led_path, sizeof(lpath) - 1);` ? Why do you truncate the path to 64 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call:

```
    rk = kernel_write(f_led, led_value, len, &f_led->f_pos);
```

The second parameter is supposed to be a `char *`, but you are passing an `int`.

In addition, when writing to the "/sys/class/leds/[device]/brightness" file, the code that handles this expects a pointer to a string of decimal digits, terminated by some non-digit character (such as a newline) or a null terminator.

You need to "print" your `led_value` to a `char` array as a decimal number and write the array contents to the file:

```
    char led_valstr[20]; /* should be large enough */

    len = scnprintf(led_valstr, sizeof(led_valstr), "%d\n", led_value);
    rk = kernel_write(f_led, led_valstr, len, &f_led->f_pos);
```

(EDIT: corrected call to `scnprintf`.)

Comment: Now kernel_write is returning the Null value (rk = 0) , is that the normal value which it must return if it operates successfully ?

Comment: It is supposed to return the number of bytes written (or a negative error code), which should be equal to `len` in this case. Perhaps it would be better to initialize a local variable `loff_t pos = 0;` and change `&f_led->f_pos` to `&pos`.

Comment: still len = 0 and rk = 0

Comment: @gaston. Sorry, I messed up the call to `scnprintf` (I omitted the second parameter, which specifies the size of the buffer). I've corrected it now.